# Reports and Dashboards stack bar chart

Tags: dashboard, custom-reports

[image]

I have created Dashboard , component type is Table which is displaying New and Enriched contact. These two are the picklist value in status.

But problem is when I run the Dashboard it is showing one more value in Blue as a 'blank' not picklist value assigned to it. I want to show only New and Enriched values on dashboards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the filter in the report which is added into dashboard to contain only New and Enriched or not contains null.

Answer (score 0):

I think That blue color means values you have not selected(you are not given field values) for those records in that picklist field(New and Enriched).

Note: if you are not selected  New or Enriched(I mean in the picklist field) for the records then it will show you in the different color.